# use of hasNext() and hasNextInt()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

As the hasNext() returns True when there is a token in buffer otherwise false And hasNextInt() return true if the token in buffer can be interpreted as int otherwise false.

If in case, the buffer is empty then they should return false, but when I do this in my code they hold the screen for taking input from the user. Why so?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(input.hasNext());
    }
}
```

OUTPUT : console Waits for my input,when i provide input it get closed.

Comment: want to know why does the console waits for my input,even though i was only checking for presence of a token in buffer by using hasNext() method.

Comment: reading data streams is different than reading from files. It will simply wait for the streams and but thats obviously infinite.
If you want to have line-by-line behaviour you need to read from files.
If you want to get the next content on a stream you can not first use hasNext and then readLine. Keep that in mind.

Comment: It seem a little counter intuitive but it is a distinction between a buffer and a stream. A stream is going to keep providing values until it is closed. If you want to know about the next elements of a stream, it doesn't really matter how long it takes the elements to be returned. It could be accessing an array (fast), reading a file (not quite as fast) or downloading something (less fast) or in your case waiting for input. A buffer on the other hand holds values, and you could ask "whats in the buffer?"

Comment: If you are looking to see whether there are characters to be read from standard input without blocking, you _may_ be able to use `System.in.available()` but it is not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 3):

The methods of scanner will block for more input if there is no current token and the source (in this case `System.in`) hasn't reached end-of-stream yet. This will then result in it waiting for your input.

This is also explicitly mentioned in the documentation of [`hasNext()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext()) (and the other blocking methods):

> This method may block while waiting for input to scan.

This can also be seen in the actual implementation of `hasNext()`:

```java
public boolean hasNext() {
    ensureOpen();
    saveState();
    modCount++;
    while (!sourceClosed) {
        if (hasTokenInBuffer()) {
            return revertState(true);
        }
        readInput();
    }
    boolean result = hasTokenInBuffer();
    return revertState(result);
}
```

As you can see, it will loop as long as the source isn't closed, and if there is no token in the buffer, it will call `readInput()` to find the next token. This read will block if there is currently nothing to read from the source at this time, but it hasn't reached end-of-stream/end-of-file yet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that many programmers are expecting hasNext() (and other has..() methods by class Scanner) only inspect the availability of input data, whereas the method also block (waiting for input) if the expected data is not available.

I think one of the ways to overcome this limitation is to create your own method to handle the input e.g. readInput() such as follows. But to get a line of text as input, simply use the nextLine() instead of using the readInput().

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ChkInput {
    
    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    // Swallow all input data each time we read input
    public static String[] readInput() {
        String in = input.nextLine();
        String[] data  = in.split("[\\s]+");
        return data;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        while(true) {
           
           System.out.println("Input a number : ");
           String[] data = readInput(); 
           
           // handle the expected input as nextInt()
           int num = Integer.parseInt( data[0] );
           System.out.println("Number is " + num);
           
           // If more data are available, do something before next loop
           // Here if expecting more data but length == 1, you know data missing.
           // so next loop get the data
           if( data.length > 1) {
               // example: just print them out.
               System.out.println("More input data waiting : ");
               for(int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                   System.out.print(data[i] + ", ");
               }
               System.out.println();
           }
        }   
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
The following is an example of implementing the idea mentioned above into a class named InputBuffer.

```
// file: ChkInput.java

import java.util.Scanner;

// InputBuffer : An implementation of using buffer to hold input.
//               With better control of hasNext() and flushing (clear data)
//
class InputBuffer {
    
    Scanner input;
    String[] buff;
    int buffIndex;
    
    // constructor
    //----
    public InputBuffer(Scanner scannerDev) throws Exception {
        if(scannerDev == null) {
            throw new Exception("Scanner is not defined");
        }
        input = scannerDev;
        buff = new String[0];
        buffIndex = 0;
    }
    // verify if any data available in buffer.
    // if no data just proceed (no blocking).
    //----
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return buffIndex < buff.length;
    }
    // read data as a token
    //----
    public String readInput()  throws Exception{
    
        if(buffIndex == buff.length) {
           String in = input.nextLine().trim();
           buff = in.split("[\\s]+");
           buffIndex = 0;
        } 
        String data = buff[ buffIndex ];
        buffIndex++;
        return data;
    }
    // read data as a line.
    // if buffer filled with tokens and a subsequent 
    // readInputLine() follows a readInput(), all 
    // tokens rejoined using space (' ')
    //----
    public String readInputLine() throws Exception {
    
        String data;
        if(buffIndex == buff.length) {
            data = input.nextLine();
        } else {
            data = "";
            for(int i = buffIndex; i < buff.length; i++ ) {
                data = data + buff[i];
                if (i < buff.length) {
                    data = data + " ";
                }
            }
        }
        flush();
        return data;
    }
    // clear remaining data in buffer
    //----
    public void flush() {
        buff = new String[0];
        buffIndex = 0;
    }
    // explicitly close the scanner device
    //---
    public void close() {
        input.close();
    }
}

// Test program
public class ChkInput {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        InputBuffer input = new InputBuffer(new Scanner(System.in));
                
        while(true) {
           System.out.println("Enter line of text (x to stop): ");
           String name = input.readInputLine();
           if (name.equals("x")) {    break; }
           
           System.out.println("Line = " + name);
           
           System.out.println("Input a number : ");
           String data = input.readInput(); 
           
           // handle the expected input like nextInt();
           int num = Integer.parseInt( data );
           System.out.println("Number is " + num);
           
           // hasNext() checks if there is another data available, do something before next loop
           // if there is no data, return false and proceed to next loop. No blocking (waiting input) by hasNext()
           if( input.hasNext()) {
               System.out.println( "Get the next data : " + input.readInput() );
           }
           input.flush();  // clear all remaining data, start fresh
        }   
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: The example codes had been updated to fix some bugs and adding improvements.

Comment: I'm not against removing `Scanner` largely from the equation, but I've got serious issues with some of the code. Examples are using a mutable instance as `static` variable in the first code block or creating a "buffer" that **implicitly** reads from `System.in` . Both are examples that increases the risk of unexpected side effects.

Comment: In the first implementation i just want to show how to create a wrapper method to get the input as a set of tokens. Just a raw idea on handling the input. With the second implementation i try to propose a more complete alternative to Scanner class, so to have more control (especially the hasNext() and flush()) for simple application. Still a simple idea. I'm only focusing on the issue of handling the input, by having the buffer. I didn't consider the case ChkInput class to be used by multithreading, if that what you mean. So your concern might be correct.

Comment: It's OK for solving the problem / showing technique, but if you create code that is clearly meant for reuse (defining a class) then you should expect copy / paste and in that case I think it is prudent that at least the interface is well thought out, and e.g. that it is possible to close a resource.

Comment: I agree with you. It's just  take more time to think about all the possibilities to suggest a good class as a library. Whereas here is to propose an idea. But I updated the InputBuffer class regarding the Scanner so that it should be defined and closed explicitly by the class user.